# Understanding $\alpha^{\frac{1}{n}}$ as a root of an equation.

Tags: calculus

In an attempt to understand the meaning of $\alpha^{\frac{1}{n}}$ for some real $\alpha$ and some positive integer $n$ I was led to study the equation $x^n=\alpha$ with unknown $x$. Obviously this equation has $n$ complex roots. I want to define  $\alpha^{\frac{1}{n}}$ with a sentence like this:  $\alpha^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is the unique real solution of the equation $x^n=\alpha$ such that ...

I could not finish the sentence. Also I see some problems, for example when $n$ is even and $\alpha$ is negative there can be no real solution and so what is the real $\alpha^{\frac{1}{n}}$ in this case ?  The case $n=2$ and $\alpha >0$ is simple because in this case we can define $\alpha^{\frac{1}{2}}$ as the unique real solution such that this solution is positive. But how can we generalize this to any $n$ ?

Moreover, this is polynomial equation with real coefficients so roots are conjugate thus if $n$ is odd we are sure of the existence of a real solution but there can be more than one real solution so how can we characterize the solution $\alpha^{\frac{1}{n}}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\alpha$ is non-negative and $n$ is even, then we define $\alpha^{1/n}$ as the unique positive, real solution to $x^n = \alpha$. If $\alpha$ is real and $n$ is odd, we define $\alpha^{1/n}$ as the unique real solution to $x^n = \alpha$. That's all there is to it. No more "such that..." needed.

Comment: So the task no is to show the existence and uniqueness of the solution in the even case and the uniqueness in the odd case, do we need to write $x=a+ib$ or $x=re^{i\theta}$ in the equation to show this ?

Comment: No, we can do that using differentiation to show that $x^n - \alpha$ is strictly monotone on the relevant interval (the whole of $\Bbb R$ if $n$ is odd, and $[0,\infty)$ if $n$ is even), so it is $0$ at most once, and $x^n - \alpha$ changes sign somewhere so the solution exists by the intermeduate value theorem.